# vscode jshint error displaying in terminal

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code, jshint

I'm getting this error in vscode. my os is windows 10. I'm using nodejs with express. I thought nodejs is not a problem. when I open my vscode, suddenly open the terminal and throw this error. I don't know what is this error.

I've tried `npm install jshint` but didn't work.

I'm facing this error last 3 month

[image: w-talent - Visual Studio Code]